# Hide <li> on different screen sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a quick responsive CSS question: I want to hide a `<li>` item when screen size is anything BUT mobile (a login button is shown when you are not in mobile, but the link should be shown instead when you are on mobile).

```
<div class="header-menu"><ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="index.php">Låna pengar</a></li>
 <li><a href="sa_fungerar_det.html">Så fungerar det</a></li>
 <li><a href="kundservice.php">Kundservice</a></li>
 <li><a href="om_oss.html">Om oss</a></li>
 <li id="loginLink"><a href="index-login.php">Logga In</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Note the last item with id "loginLink". Thats the one I want to hide. So far, in the css, I am doing the following for all @media except the 360px one:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:940px) {
 #loginLink { display: none; }
 // a lot of other css here
}
```

But it doesn't fire? What am I missing?

Comment: seems fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/DT8s5/ sure you dont have any conflicting CSS?

Comment: As @SW4 pointed out it's more than likely a conflict, I would add an `!important` just to 100% clarify it is a conflict, then go search and fix the conflict and remove the !important.

Comment: It was. Arrrgh! Thanks for the quick answer SW4.

Comment: Quick follow up.. It hides, but now I can't get it to show when it goes down to mobile? This is what I added:#loginLinkRGB { display: block; }

Comment: Because you have it displaying none up to a max width of 940px. You need something like this: `@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:940px)`

Comment: There are several @media tags in the .css file, ill list them in correct order (had to removes the @ signs):

media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
media only screen and (max-width:940px)
media only screen and (max-width:800px)
media only screen and (max-width:768px)
media only screen and (max-width:768px)
media only screen and (max-width:360px)
media only screen and (max-width:320px)
media(min-width:768px)
media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:1250px)
media(max-width:768px)